# Remove next td - javascript

Tags: jquery

whats error in my code?. remove next one td element if it is empty. I am Struggling with this code.

```
$(document).on("click", ".expand_img" , function(e ) {       
        var ColsCount =$(this).parents('td').next('td').length;
        var counter =0;
        var nextCols = $(this).parents('td').next('td');
        if (nextCols.contents().length == 0) {
                $(this).hide();         }
        var next = $(this).parents('td').next('td');
            if ((next.contents().length == 0) && ($(this).parents('td').next('td').length==1)){
                next.remove();
            }
         if (ColsCount!="") {
            $(this).parents('td').attr('colSpan', '' + parseInt(ColsCount + 1,10) + '')
         }
        else if(ColsCount=="") {
            counter = 1;
         }

    });
```

my html code is here

```
<tr>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1">
      <span>
        <img src="images/Close-icon.png" class="close_img">
        <img src="images/expand.png" class="expand_img">iPod
      </span></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you could create a jsfiddle

Comment: please share your html code also

Comment: your code works fine for me?

Comment: Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent()` to access the element's parent and NOT `.parents('td')`.

Readup: [`.parent()` | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

In your code, you were accessing the wrong parent. `.parent()` will give you the `<span>` and `.parent().parent()` will give you the `<td>` that you need.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".expand_img" , function(e ) {       
  var ColsCount =$(this).parents('td').next('td').length;
  var counter =0;
  var nextCols = $(this).parent().parent().next('td');
  if (nextCols.contents().length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();         }
  var next = $(this).parents('td').next('td');
  if ((next.contents().length == 0) && ($(this).parent().parent().next('td').length==1)){
    next.remove();
  }
  if (ColsCount!="") {
    $(this).parents('td').attr('colSpan', '' + parseInt(ColsCount + 1,10) + '')
  }
  else if(ColsCount=="") {
    counter = 1;
  }

});
```

```css
table, tr, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1">
      <span>
        <img src="images/Close-icon.png" class="close_img">
        <img src="images/expand.png" class="expand_img">
        iPod
      </span>
    </td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
    <td class="ui-droppable ui-sortable content" colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: about to answer but you posted,+1

Answer (score 1):

use **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to find the `closest td` of `expand_im`g

```
 var nextCols = $(this).closest("td").next('td');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".expand_img" , function(e ) {       
    var colsSpan = 0;
    var $parentTD = $(this).closest('td');//get parent td of image clicked
    //iterate through next td 
    while($parentTD.next('td').length > 0)
    {
      var $nextTD = $parentTD.next('td');

      if($nextTD.contents().length == 0)
        {
          $nextTD.remove();
          colsSpan++;
        }
      else
       {
        //shift to next to parent td
        $parentTD = $nextTD;
       }
     }

    if(colsSpan > 0)
      $(this).closest('td').attr('colSpan',colsSpan);        
});
```